# ReSharper Unit Test Runner fails in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

I've recently updated my development environment and stared getting this message:

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   Miscrosoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.OutOfProcTestPlatform..ctor
>   (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestRunnerServiceClient,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient)'

[image]

Any ideas?